# Как передать параметр из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

у меня в БД сущность координаты представлена 3-мя полями Name, CoordX,CoordY. Объявлен state:{coord:{}}, который после get запроса примет значения из бд и получается массив объектов.{[name:"...",CoordX:"...",CoordY:"..."],[и.т.д]}.

Как мне в `<Placemark [coordinates(x,y)], hitcontent:name/>`значения эти передать?

Ведь placemark координаты как массив принимает , а у меня они отдельными объектами.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял вопрос.

Можно написать так:

```
const cordsArray = coords.map(({CoordX, CoordY})=>[CoordX, CoordY])
// создаётся массив массивов с координатами [ [x,y], [x,y], [x,y] ]

    ...

<Placemark coords={cordsArray} ... />
```

Или так:

```
{array.map(({name, CoordX, CoordY})=>(
    <Placemark coords={[CoordX, CoordY] hitcontent={name} />}
))}
```

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо. Но возник еще один вопрос, мб подскажите, вверху прикрепил изображение.  Причем когда я объявляю какую ни то константу допустим const COORD = {"1":[52.5252,52.5252],"2":[43.53252,53.5325]} и работаю с ней, все сравнивает корректно

Comment: Все, разобрался и с этим, нужно было к строке преобразовать.